# (Django Rest Framework) How Do I Update The User Model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to update the user model (with Django Rest Framework's patch method in APIView) but i keep getting the error.

```
`NotImplementedError: update() must be implemented.`
```

Here is my Serializer:

```
class UpdateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name',
              'phone')
```

Here is my View:

```
class UpdateUser(APIView):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    ]

    def patch(self, request):
        """
        `Update User`
        """
        user = self.request.user
        serializer = UpdateSerializer(user, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I created a custom user model, my serializer for registering users works fine but this update serializer is giving that error

Comment: Where is the function `update()` being called for in your code? Are you trying to call the function called `patch()` maybe? Can you post more of the stack trace (so that we can see where `update()` is being called from for example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**`serializers.ModelSerializer`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) instead of `serializers.Serializer`

```
class UpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone')
```